# rails advanced find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :jobs
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :address
end
```

I'm trying to get all categories that the jobs has address_id != NULL
I'm almost there doing:

```
categories = Category.find(:all,:joins=>:jobs,:conditions=>'jobs.address_id is not null')
```

the problem is that i have a lot of repeated categories. I can solve it doing a:

categories.uniq!

but is not exactly the best solution.. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you have different categories with the same category name? If so you can try this:

```
categories = Category.find(:all,:joins=>:jobs,
           :conditions=>'jobs.address_id is not null', :group => "category.name")
```

**Note:** If there are several categories with the same name you will get one of them. You have no control over the specific row returned to you.

Comment: i must review the results, but at least you were in the right direction.